# grid needed to perform edit, delete, add new row and DragDrop rows in asp.net 3.5

Tags: gridview, asp.net-3.5

Please suggest me a grid which performs the Add, Edit, Delete and DragDrop rows. Is our normal GridView suffice this requirement? or should I go for DevExpress Grid or some other third party grids?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming by re-order, you mean sort? If you use a dataset, the gridview should take care of all of this functionality for you.

If you mean something else by reorder, you are going to have to do some hand coding, or use something like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DragAndDropGridView.aspx perhaps.